# Should all async calls be executed by the same thread in order to be thread safe?

Tags: asynchronous

I am little bit confused right now with the async/await call now. In my code, I have a chain of async calls. 
The code looks like

```
public async Task<T> MethodA(){ do something; return await MethodB();}
public async Task<T> MethodB(){ do something; return await MethodC();}
public async Task<T> MethodC(){ return something; }
```

By looking at the CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId, I found out that each async call's thread are different. Some one told me this might cause problems because it's not thread safe.

can someone please tell me is that argument true or not? Does all calls need use the same thread?

Comment: I think you need some basic research first on what "thread safety" means. You need that in order to understand the answers. If you don't know thread safety you should not mess with async at all...